# Why does my code run without 'Option Explicit' but fail with it?

Tags: excel, vba

I am constructing my first major program in VBA (With some help from SO).  The beginning of it is below, and I am adding blocks of code in as structured a way as possible.  Having read about the importance of using 'Option Explicit' though, I inserted it and started to declare all my variables.  Running the program gave - 'Compile Error: Variable not Defined'.

I have tried deleting and re-entering declarations in case the problem was caused by me adding 'Option Explicit' after starting on the code, as well as removing the UDF and adding that back in, but without success.

Commenting out 'Option Explicit' does away with the error message and the subsequent blocks of code run exactly as designed.

EDIT:I should have said that the error always occurs with 'iLoopControl'.

```
Option Explicit

'UDF to roll a number of Dice of specified size and total them
  Function Dice(NoOfDice, DiceSize)
    Dice = 0
      For iLoopControl = 1 To NoOfDice
        Dice = Dice + WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, DiceSize)
      Next
  End Function

Sub MercOne()

Randomize

Dim Merc(86)
Dim Temp As Integer, TechLevel As Byte, ArmOfService As Byte
Dim Year As Byte, YearCount As Byte
Dim GenAssignment As Variant, UnitAssignment As Variant
Dim SpecAssignmentSwitchEnd As Byte, Roll As Byte
Dim Rank As Variant, NoOfDice As Variant, DiceSize As Byte
Dim GenAssignmentSwitchInt As Byte, GenAssignmentSwitchOff As Byte
Dim CharacterNumber As Long, iLoopControl As Long
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Option Explicit` means you must explicitly declare all variables and their types before using them. If you don't include the `Option Explicit` declaration, then VBA will just create `Variant` type variables whenever it encounters a new identifier.

So for example, you need to include `Dim iLoopControl as Integer` if you have declared `Option Explicit`:

```
Option Explicit    
Dim iLoopControl As Integer
For iLoopControl = 1 To NoOfDice
   Dice = Dice + WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, DiceSize)
Next
```

If you didn't include `Option Explicit` then you could just use `iLoopControl` without using the `Dim iLoopControl as Integer` to declare it.

Answer (score 3):

I applaud you for using `Option Explicit`! Now you have to learn to use it well...

You have to declare a variable *before* using it. You use `iLoopControl` in your function `Dice` before declaring it. VBA will assume (absent Option Explicit) that you were just lazy, and create a Variant variable for you. But if you misspelled the variable name, it would create a new one - and debugging would be really difficult because you won't understand why values are wrong...

As an aside, it is a good idea to avoid `Variant` in general, except when you know the variable can contain different types, when you will use it in a `For Each` loop, or when it is an optional parameter in a function. It is slower than a "regularly typed" variable and takes more space. In larger programs that can make a difference. And if you do want a Variant, you don't need to say `As Variant` since that is implied.

One more point about your code: you declare `iLoopControl` in the *scope* of a `Sub`. That means it is unknown (and "undeclared") when you are not in that sub. Not even when you are inside a function called from that sub. The only variables that can be "seen" inside a Sub/Function are the ones that are declared at the *module level* (outside of sub/function), or *within* the sub itself.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail, I'll add it to my list of 'Things to Remember about VBA'.  I'm sorry I can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to declare variables before using it
2. Where's `End Sub` for `MercOne()`?

Comment: This is just the opening part of the program, there are several blocks of code after it, ending of course with 'End Sub'.