# Invalid use of Null VBA Excel

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, adodb

Please find the below table and code. I am facing **Invalid use of Null** Error

**Table 1**

[image]

**Table 2**

[image]

**VBA code:-**

```
Sub sql()

sql_string = "Select [Sheet1$].[Sr], [Sheet2$].[Name], [Sheet2$].[Value] From [Sheet1$]" & _
 " Inner Join [Sheet2$] On CInt([Sheet1$].[Sr]) = CInt(Mid([Sheet2$].[Name],InStr(1,[Sheet2$].[Name],""#"")+1))"

sq = SQL_query(sql_string)

end sub


Function SQL_query(ByRef sql_string As Variant)

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = sql_string

rs.Open strSQL, cn

Sheet5.Range("A21").CopyFromRecordset rs  ''HERE I AM FACING ERROR

End Function
```

Please guide me.. on my below error.

[image]

In **table2 column Sr** after **#** there are some number's which is similar to **table1 column Sr** number's.I want to do inner join as per that particular number.

required output.

[image]

Comment: Which line gives this error? Also, please describe what is this code doing and what do you want to get.

Comment: @MichaelO. Updated the require output in question , also in the last line i am facing code  **Sheet5.Range("A21").CopyFromRecordset rs**

Comment: Have you checked if the connection is established and the recordset is opened succesfully?

Comment: @MichaelO. Yes Sir, Its opened successfully..

Comment: What does the recordset contain? Are there some NULLs?

Comment: @MichaelO. I delete the **NULL** value and now macro is run correctly, Please guide how can i handle these errors..

Comment: I don't know much about this, try to google `excel adodb null`

Comment: In case you think there will be null values in your dataset, then don't use CopyFromRecordset. Rather, go row by row and check for null in each fields.

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing `Option Explicit` on top of the module. [Why does my code run without 'Option Explicit' but fail with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014154/why-does-my-code-run-without-option-explicit-but-fail-with-it)

Then change the `Sub sql()` to something like this:

```
Function sql_string() as string

    sql_string = "Select [Sheet1$].[Sr], [Sheet2$].[Name], [Sheet2$].[Value] From [Sheet1$]" & _
     " Inner Join [Sheet2$] On CInt([Sheet1$].[Sr]) = CInt(Mid([Sheet2$].[Name],InStr(1,[Sheet2$].[Name],""#"")+1))"

end sub
```

- In the immediate window, write `?sql_string` and see what you get.
- Find a way to test what you get